# How to get data where time column (LocalDateTime) has 00 minutes?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I need query to retrieve all entities from database who has 00 minutes in TIME column which is represented as LocalDateTime?

Check here what i need -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Ufc.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use EXTRACT():

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fb_data
WHERE   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "time") = 0;
```